# Javascript not loading when php in it

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem when I open php tags inside script tags it doesn't load any of javascript code and when I remove php tags it works normaly.Why is that hapening?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("aa");
    <?php
    $js_array = json_encode($podaci);
    echo $js_array;
    echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
    ?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: check browser **developer** tools console - also the view page source as the browser gets it (ctrl-U)

Comment: `document.write` - welcome to the 21st century, time traveller :p

Comment: I assume that `echo $js_array` and `echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n"` do not work so well together.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
    $js_array = json_encode($podaci);
  ?>
<script>
    document.write("aa");
    var javascript_array = '<?php echo $js_array; ?>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $js_array;
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
```

will give something like this :
`"[1, 2, 'foo', 'bar']"var javascript_array = [1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'];` which is - obviously - an invalid javascript statement.

Just remove `echo $js_array` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
<script>
    document.write("aa");
    var js_array = '<?php echo json_encode($podaci); ?>';
    document.write("var javascript_array = "+js_array);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your php tags in quotation:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("aa");
    var phpContents = '<?php $js_array = json_encode($podaci);?>';
    var javascript_array = "<?php echo $js_array;?> \n";
    alert(javascript_array);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```